# How can I write a Hudson/Jenkins email-ext template in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, email-ext

I want to write a custom email template for Jenkins using the email-ext plugin. The [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) mentions I can use JavaScript for this, but has no further JavaScript-specific documentation.

I would much prefer to use JavaScript instead of Groovy; all of the examples I have been able to find use the latter.

How do I go about writing a template like this in JavaScript? Which API do I use? How do I do the actual templating--is there some template format, or do I just return a string, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Groovy and Jelly engines are supported (or were supported as of a month ago).

Comment: I don't know, the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) (in the "Script content" section) says that "New to version 2.15 is the ability to use Groovy or JavaScript scripts...". Of course, it could be lying.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wanted to write a Python script and discovered that it was not supported (although it is JSR223 compatible language), so I extrapolated to other languages as well. BTW, I ended up writing my script in Groovy.

Comment: I fixed the documentation, only Groovy is supported.